# Numpy, all pairwise correlations of a 3d array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array of shape (l,m,n). I'm trying to calculate a distance matrix of shape (l,m,n) where entry (i,j,k) is the coefficient between vectors (i,j,:) and (i,:,k).  I haven't found anything in numpy or scipy that fits the bill.

I tried using a for loop and iterating along axis 0, then feeding that to scipy.spatial.distance.pdist, but that takes a long time as pdist itself uses a nested for loop.  In essence, what I would like to do would be to perform pdist down axis 0, but ideally make it so pdist doesn't use for loops either....

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I would personally write a little Cython function to do this ( http://cython.org). Write and test an iterative pure Python version (with for loops), move it to a .pyx Cython file, add type declarations and follow the NumPy integration guide:

http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html

Might seem like work but if you're doing computing in Python, some basic Cython skills are well worth cultivating as it makes writing C extensions much easier.

Answer (score 0):

> Any thoughts?

1. First thought is that you cannot compute such distances as long as m != n
2. Second thought is that internal loops of `pdist` should not bother you if those are written in C, so the probable reason is not in implementation, but in the amount of computations needed
3. Final thought is that your problem may be solved by numpy.einsum and linear algebra:

Code (which I assume to be optimal):

```
products = numpy.einsum('ijl, ilk -> ijk')
distances = numpy.einsum('ijj -> ij', products)
distances = distances[:, :, None] + distances[:, None, :] - 2 * product
```